# How to boxplot depending on a column value (user-id) and a range of timestamps ( hourly )

Tags: python, datetime, boxplot

I am a newbie in Python and I've been trying to create different boxplots for my different users for each month. Each boxplot is affiliated to a a specific user for a consumption value in Kwh, and I want the X-axis to contain months from the beginning of my experience to the end and the Y-axis the value.

This is my dataframe:

|  | ID_ADDRESS | ENERTSTAMP | VALUE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 53 | 2019-10-30 14:00:00.000000 | 0.106000 |
| 1 | 53 | 2019-10-30 15:00:00.000000 | 0.016000 |
| 2 | 53 | 2019-10-30 16:00:00.000000 | 0.041000 |
| 3 | 53 | 2019-10-30 17:00:00.000000 | 0.140000 |
| 4 | 53 | 2019-10-30 18:00:00.000000 | 0.395000 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 121703 | 73 | 2021-05-31 23:00:00.000000 | 0.099148 |
| 121704 | 75 | 2021-05-31 23:00:00.000000 | 0.162000 |
| 121705 | 77 | 2021-05-31 23:00:00.000000 | 0.587000 |
| 121706 | 255 | 2021-05-31 23:00:00.000000 | 0.122000 |
| 121707 | 466 | 2021-05-31 23:00:00.000000 | 0.168000 |

I tried to sort and groupby then use a for loop, but doesn't seem to work. I need some guidance. Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't really understand the layout of the figure, you say that you want the x axis to be months and y axis to be values, but you also want one boxplot for each user. Do you want one figure for each user, that contains a box for each month (with the y-axis the value)? (Then you would have as many figures as you have users, which could be a lot)

Comment: @Stryder yes exactly ! as many figures as my users, each box for a month with the y-axis being the value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting with this sample df:

```
df
Out: 
    ID               Stamp     Value
0    0 2021-01-03 23:17:00  8.322590
1    0 2021-01-04 14:46:00  0.955291
2    0 2021-01-05 02:26:00  2.956634
3    0 2021-01-06 20:57:00  4.212490
4    0 2021-01-09 16:28:00  9.219869
..  ..                 ...       ...
95   9 2021-06-25 06:01:00  1.073370
96   9 2021-06-26 22:37:00  8.251078
97   9 2021-06-29 06:20:00  2.502405
98   9 2021-06-29 11:50:00  9.860154
99   9 2021-06-30 14:26:00  8.563433
```

I first extract the month to be able to group the data by it

```
df["month"] = pd.Index(df.Stamp).to_period("M")
df
Out: 
    ID               Stamp     Value    month
0    0 2021-01-03 23:17:00  8.322590  2021-01
1    0 2021-01-04 14:46:00  0.955291  2021-01
2    0 2021-01-05 02:26:00  2.956634  2021-01
3    0 2021-01-06 20:57:00  4.212490  2021-01
4    0 2021-01-09 16:28:00  9.219869  2021-01
..  ..                 ...       ...      ...
95   9 2021-06-25 06:01:00  1.073370  2021-06
96   9 2021-06-26 22:37:00  8.251078  2021-06
97   9 2021-06-29 06:20:00  2.502405  2021-06
98   9 2021-06-29 11:50:00  9.860154  2021-06
99   9 2021-06-30 14:26:00  8.563433  2021-06
```

Then I can call groupby and boxplot like this:

```
df.set_index("ID").groupby("ID").boxplot(by = "month")
```

It's best to have the index set to "ID", then you also groupby "ID". When you then call boxplot on the groupby object, this will create a plot for each group, which will then also be grouped `by= "month"`

For me it yields this:[image]

*to make it prettier, you will have to look into matplotlib and everything about boxplots, that's beyond the scope of this answer, but I hope it works for you*

Comment: Thank you very much, it works perfectly !